# akka actors are not working as expected

Tags: java, akka

akka novice here. Currently building a system to call some web services and update database... but akka actors are not working exactly as expected...My code sample...

**Application Runner**

```
public class Application
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
  {
    ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("system");
    ActorRef master = system.actorOf(Props.create(MasterActor.class));
    String url = "http://some-web-service-url";
    master.tell(url, ActorRef.noSender());
    system.shutdown();
  }
}
```

**MasterActor**

```
public class MasterActor extends UntypedActor
{
  private final LoggingAdapter log = Logging.getLogger(getContext().system(), getSelf());
  private final ActorRef childActor = getContext().actorOf(Props.create(ChildActor.class));    

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception
  {
    if(message instanceof String)
    {
      childActor.tell(message, getSelf());
    }else if(message instanceof Boolean){
      log.info("all done");
    }else {
      unhandled(message);
    }
  }
}
```

**ChildActor**

```
public class ChildActor extends UntypedActor
{
  private final LoggingAdapter log = Logging.getLogger(getContext().system(), getSelf());

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception
  {
    if (message instanceof String) {
      String url = (String) message;
      Integer result = getWebServiceResult(url);
      log.info("result: {}", result);
      getSender().tell(true, getSelf());
    }else {
      unhandled(message);
    }
  }

  private Integer getWebServiceResult(final String url) throws Exception
  {
    ExecutionContextExecutor executor = getContext().dispatcher();
    Future<Integer> future = Futures.future(new Callable<Integer>()
    {
      @Override
      public Integer call() throws Exception
      {
        return new HttpClient().fetchData(url); //some web service call
      }
    }, executor);
    return (Integer) Await.result(future, Duration.create(7000, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
  }
}
```

**but child actor is unable to send the message to its sender, master...getting this error stack...**

```
[INFO] [03/28/2015 01:02:45.521] [system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://system/user/$a/$a] result: TheWebservice Result
[INFO] [03/28/2015 01:02:45.528] [system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://system/user/$a] Message [java.lang.Boolean] from Actor[akka://system/user/$a/$a#1601481298] to Actor[akka://system/user/$a#1257171720] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

I am unable to find what's wrong (spent 3 days)... In my sense this code should work...can you tell me what's I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Just a first guess, but have you tried _not_ immediately trying to shut down everything after sending the first message? Just give them a second or so.

Answer (score 3):

You have a race condition. You're shutting down your `ActorSystem`

```
system.shutdown();
```

before the child actor has a chance to send its reply. Remember that more or less everything in akka is asynchronous.

Add, for example, a

```
Thread.sleep(someTime);
```

before the `shutdown` to see the message sent and received.

Comment: Thread.sleep(2000);  works. but as I don't know how long it will take to finish the web services call and database call.. shouldn't the system wait for all child to finish?

Comment: @Shakil The system can't know exactly what the children are doing. What if a child spawn a thread to send a message in 10 hours? How does the system know about that? No, it can't. You'll need an external signal to shutdown the System. (Basically the System should live forever.)

Comment: I agree with @SotiriosDelimanolis however this sounds like a nice use-case for the future/pipe pattern (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/futures.html) e.g. `akka.pattern.Patterns.pipe(future, system.dispatcher()).to(actor);`. You can then either change the future slightly to return boolean, or change the master to handle messages of type Integer. Everything will be handled in a non-blocking way, and the system will begin the shut down process only when then the web service result future completes

Answer (score 0):

Just to deal with the exit part : 
You could register a shutdown hook like below and shutdown the akka system in it

```
   Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                system.shutdown();
            }
        });
```

Then enter into a never ending loop as shown below while waiting for the processing to complete so that when it is done processing you press Ctrl + C on your terminal or raise a System.exit(0) within your code.

```
while(false == shutdownFlag){
  Thread.sleep(sometime);
}
```

Comment: `while(true)` is very bad code - without being manually interrupted such an application will deadlock. At least use `while(false == shutdownFlag)` or something similar, that will at least get rid of that common mistake